"Optimizing Queries Using SELECT Statements and WHERE Clauses"
How can this SQL query, using only the SELECT and WHERE clauses, be optimized for better performance?
SELECT TOP 1
    1 AS FligthExist
FROM
    FlightDetails AF
WHERE
    AF.FlightDate = '2024-11-19'
    AND AF.flightNumber = '3366'
    AND AF.CarrierCode = 'ABC'
    AND AF.FlightOrigin = 'CC'
    AND AF.FlightDestination = 'DD'
    AND AF.FlightStatus != 'CAN';


If you are using TOP then almost certainly you're not running Oracle or MySQL, but probably SQL Server or maybe Access.  What is your actual database?

Please add the table definition as text and the execution plan.

How long does it take to execute right now?

I have removed the mysql and oracle tags, because the syntax you show is not supported on those implementations. Please do not apply tags other than the brand of SQL database you are using. Doing that does not help you get a solution.

Use SSMS, execute the query and then press CTRL + L. This will likely show you some posisble improvements.

To optimize your query, you should create a composite index on the columns used in the WHERE clause, ordered by their selectivity. In your case, the ideal index would be:
CREATE INDEX IX_FlightDetails_Filter
ON FlightDetails (FlightDate, flightNumber, CarrierCode, FlightOrigin, FlightDestination, FlightStatus);

This index helps the database quickly filter rows matching the conditions without scanning the entire table.

Or perhaps flightNumber before FlightDate.

Make sure that the columns used in your WHERE clause have indexes.
Ensure date column is using the correct format amd ensure that SQL Server isn't performing a type conversion that could affect the performance.
You can also add an ORDER BY clause and ensure it has a index.
